# spring integration jms traceability

Tags: spring-integration

We have a requirement to add the traceability (to add trace-id and spell-id) for incoming and outgoing JMS messages in controller module which is based on Spring Integration. Can anyone help me with the interceptor that can be used for this which can intercept all request coming into JMS queue and all the request that will be send onto the queue.

Below is the code snippet:

```
            <!-- Need to trace the message once we receive in incoming_queue -->
            <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" channel="channel_1" 
            destination-name="incoming_queue"></int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>   

            <!-- Need to trace the message before we send the message to outgoing_queue -->
            <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOut" 
                    channel="channel_1" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                    destination-name="outgoing_queue"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On both side there is a `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` with this JavaDoc:

```
* This implementation copies JMS API headers (e.g. JMSReplyTo) to and from
 * Spring Integration Messages. Any user-defined properties will also be copied
 * from a JMS Message to a Spring Integration Message, and any other headers
 * on a Spring Integration Message (beyond the JMS API headers) will likewise
 * be copied to a JMS Message. Those other headers will be copied to the
 * general properties of a JMS Message whereas the JMS API headers are passed
 * to the appropriate setter methods (e.g. setJMSReplyTo).
```

So, if your those `trace-id` and `spell-id` are in compatible types:

```
private static List<Class<?>> SUPPORTED_PROPERTY_TYPES = Arrays.asList(new Class<?>[] {
        Boolean.class, Byte.class, Double.class, Float.class, Integer.class, Long.class, Short.class, String.class });
```

You are good to send and receive those headers.

If you think about something like logging those headers, you definitely can take a look into the `ChannelInterceptor` implementation to log those headers before/after sending/receiving to/from JMS.

Comment: Thank you so much Artem. I was able to achieve what I wanted to do.